# Using "for" or "in" with perfect tenses

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

I am not sure about the difference between "for" and "in" with perfect tenses. Is there a difference in meaning?

> 1- She hasn't taken her eyes off her phone ***in two hours***.
>
> 2- She hasn't taken her eyes off her phone ***for two hours***.
>
> 3- We haven't talked ***in 10 years***.
>
> 4- We haven't talked ***for 10 years***.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, there's no difference in meaning.

"In" suggests *within* some given time period, while "for" suggests some given *duration* of time ... but this is, as we say, ["six of one, half-dozen of the other"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other), meaning it's two different ways of saying the same thing.